# Exporting to text file the coordinates and value for section of map

Tags: qgis, export, coordinates

I'm a novice with GIS. I want to export to a text (.csv) file the coordinates (lat, lon) and data values for a rectangular section of the data domain as shown on the map. I have loaded a .img file of landcover for Alaska and the map is displayed in my QGIS 3.24 on Ubuntu 20.04. From what I understand, to select a region and export to text, this may involve

1. Creating another layer,
2. Making a selection from the original layer and copying selection to new layer,
3. Save the attribute table.

Maybe this involves a shapefile? In the text file the header will have "latitude" "longitude" "landcover" followed by N rows (grids).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].

Comment: Specifics please on what you want to do and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you need: Use the GDAL tool *gdal2xyz* from the Processing Toolbox:
[image]
This will allow you to output to a csv file:

[image]
The csv file will have longitude, latitude, data value :
[image]

If you only want to do it for a section of the img file then use *Clip Raster by extent* (Raster menu>Extraction>) function before the *gdaltoxyz* and select your area by one of the available methods:

[image]

Comment: Before attempting your solution, I'd like to know if I should operate on the single layer for all of Alaska, or can and should I make a copy layer that I'll then clip by extent? I ask because I want to repeat this for a few other sections of the Alaska domain. I see there's a Layer -> Copy Layer.

Comment: I have created a duplicate layer (right click on the layer in layer panel) and will work on it for clip by extent.

Comment: If you duplicate a layer, it still points to the same dataset - you are just duplicating the layer in the project- not the dataset.  A layer is a pointer to a dataset and only exists in the project file. The layer points to where the data is and holds properties including symbology, CRS,labels etc.  You don't need to create a copy of the data to run gdal2xyz especially as it doesn't change the data - just creates a new csv file.  Though sometimes it can be useful to run a function on a smaller dataset just to give you an idea of how it works and how long it will take.

Comment: gdal2xyz produced a csv file with x and y but I need latitude and longitude. Here's the GDAL command from log:
gdal2xyz.py -band 1 /home/user/Proj/LTER/GIS/NLCDCanningclip.tiff /home/user/Proj/LTER/GIS/grids_NLCD_Canning.csv

Comment: gdal2xyz will output in whatever the CRS is so if your CRS is unprojected (lat/long values) it will output lat/long.  If your CRS is projected (most likely metres) it will output in the coordinates of the CRS.  If your data is projected then use the GDAL>Warp function in the geoprocessing toolbox(this will create a new dataset)  before you run gdal2xyz.

Comment: I have used warp function to change CRS to **WGS 84 / NSIDC EASE-Grid 2.0 Global**, which is the one I mainly use. The map looks fine. But now having trouble clipping that layer raster by extent by drawing on map. In the Clip Raster by Extent dialog the input layer shows the reprojected on, but the clipping extent shows the original CRS. In the log it says "Warning 1: Computed -srcwin 89209 23623 813 1429 falls completely outside raster extent. Going on however...." The layer does not display afterward.

Comment: If you are talking about CRS ESPG:6933 - that is a projected CRS.  You could warp to change to WGS84 ESPG:4326 - which is unprojected.

Comment: A reprojection to CRS ESPG:6933 actually would be best. I am working primarily on that projection for my research. Actually at 1 km resolution. It would be helpful to learn how to take any raster layer and reproject to 6933 at 1 km, the default grid for all my work. I assume I could still make gdal2xyz output with the latitudes and longitudes for the ESPG:6933 since the GIS has them in association with the x and y coordinates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135304/discussion-between-aquamarine-and-rawlins02).